# -webkit-mask-image не работает в firefox

Tags: css, css3, firefox

Здравствуйте.
Может кто-то сталкивался с таким, можно ли как-то это решить через js ?
Чтобы mask-image применялась в firefox?

Comment: webkit- и не будет работать в firefox , webkit - для google chrome

Answer (score 1):

В Firefox это свойство `mask`.

Вот пример из [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask).

```
.target {
  mask: url(#c1) luminance;
}

.anothertarget {
  mask: url(resources.svg#c1) 50px 30px/10px 10px repeat-x exclude;
}
```

Comment: Маска почему-то не добавляется. Хотя свойство действует..

Comment: @СергейРумянцев, добавьте в код вопроса рабочий пример с демонстрацией проблемы, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sndkwn6o/2/

Comment: @СергейРумянцев, Firefox нужно svg-изображение для маски.